# PHP spout read/write speed

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am using the spout library for reading and writing excel files in PHP. I just have a question on speed.

When I try to read/write 100k records it only took 15 min
When I try to read/write 200k records it now took 1.5 hours

I tried uploading 600k records overnight and took 9 hours.

I don't know if it's my machine or what. But it is increasing the generation time not only by the double.

Any tips for speeding it up?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `Spout` !== `PHPExcel`

Answer (score 1):

The time Spout takes to write data to a spreadsheet should be more or less proportional to the size of the dataset. Reading a spreadsheet is different though. There are 3 possible options:

- your spreadsheet uses inline strings instead of shared strings: reading time should be proportional to the dataset size.
- your spreadsheet uses shared strings:

  - the number of shared strings is limited and can fit in memory: reading time should be proportional to the dataset size.
  - there are too many shared strings to fit in memory: Spout will then split the shared strings into chunks that can fit in memory. Each chunk is saved to disk and only the chunk containing the string being read is loaded in memory.

With the 2 first options, everything is fine and Spout goes as fast as possible. With the 3rd option though, things take longer. That's the catch to avoid going out of memory...
If the spreadsheet uses shared strings that are more or less ordered (A1 uses string 1, B1 uses string 2... Z10 uses string 840), the perf hit won't be that bad (it adds a few IO operations to read data from disk). But if the shared strings are not (A1 uses string 1 but B1 uses string 200,000 - stored in another chunk - and C1 uses string 3), because Spout reads cells sequentially, it will have to do a lot more IO operations to load the correct chunks in memory.

So back to your problem, you can take a look at how your data is defined in the XML files describing your spreadsheet. If you used Spout to create the spreadsheet, make sure to use inline strings (the final file size will be bigger but reading it will be way faster).

Something else you can do is modify this file: [CachingStrategyFactory.php](https://github.com/box/spout/blob/a8eb7ad39cfd7ae92889a361f72e5090b5a9095b/src/Spout/Reader/XLSX/Helper/SharedStringsCaching/CachingStrategyFactory.php#L40). If you know all your characters will be 1 byte characters, you'll be able to increase the number of strings you can put in memory by 4 (as Spout assumes 4-bytes characters to do its computation).

Hope that helps!